Non-Buddhist gods
I know what Buddhism teaches about 6 realms,and devas in particular.But what is the Buddhist take on,say,pagan gods-to what kind of entity people turn when they say they work with Thor for example,or any other pagan/heathen god?What are they according to Buddhism?

AFAIK the Indo-Greek kingdoms of old followed Buddhism and Hellenic religion together. My history professor once said (in jest, obviously) that they probably prayed to Nike for victory before battle, then to Buddha for forgiveness after.

While I personally have not thoroughly investigated/researched what I will post, I guess most, if not all, of the Buddhist gods represent a certain moral archetype.
I would guess what differentiates a pagan god, such as Thor, from a Buddhist god, is that Buddhism, from a worldly perspective, concerns itself primarily with social morality; where as a pagan god, such as Thor, may concern itself with military power.
As examples, Pali scriptures, such as SN 11.5 and AN 3.37, refers to three classes of gods, namely, devas (benevolent gods), asuras (demonic gods) and the Four Great Kings. AN 3.37 says the Four Great Kings and the Benevolent Gods are concerned about how many people behave properly toward their mother and father, behave properly toward ascetics and brahmins, honor the elders of the family, observe the uposatha ('sabbath'), keep the extra observance days and do meritorious deeds. The reason they are concerned about this in AN 3.37 is because if people do not live by these basic social virtues, then the world will fall under the power of the demonic gods (asura). For example, today's Western world is primarily ruled by demonic gods because most of the society has lost its basic human social virtues. It is the moral corruption & degeneracy of the common people that allows corrupt immoral politicians & unelected bureaucrats (asura) to come to & remain in power.
Other classes of moral gods in Buddhism are listed at this link: The Thirty-one Planes of Existence. Some of these gods represent those who have highly developed loving-kindness & compassion (Brahma gods) or who have developed various levels of superhuman meditations (called 'jhana') of radiance & glory.
One class of gods are the paranimmita vasavatti deva (heavenly gods with power over the creations of others). Doing a quick browse finds the scripture Iti 95, which says:

Mendicants, there are these three ways of being provided with sensual
pleasures. What three? Some sensual pleasures are simply present; some
are for those who love to imagine/delight in creation (nimmānaratino);
and some are for those who control what is imagined/created by others
(paranimmitavasavattino). These are the three ways of being provided
with sensual pleasures.
Sensual pleasures that are simply present,
gods who control what is imagined by others (ye devā vasavattino);
gods who love to imagine (nimmānaratino devā),
and others who indulge in sensual pleasures—
They go from this state to another,
but don’t escape transmigration (saṁsāraṁ).
Knowing this danger in sensual indulgence,
an astute person would forsake all sensual pleasures,
both human and heavenly (godly).

If we ponder the above, it appears to indicate:

People can indulge in basic sensual pleasures in ways they provide simply for themselves, such as via eating food or engaging in sexual activity.

People can indulge in more refined sensual pleasures they create for/to themselves, such as a musician playing music for/to themself.

People can indulge in more refined sensual pleasures created by others, such as being brainwashed by famous musicians, who are literally treated like gods. Or lots of social engineering via the entertainment industry is by 'gods' who brainwash people via sensual pleasures to develop wrong moral & political views.


In summary, while i have never studied the subject, it is possible pagan gods represent the basic powers of nature (such as the sun, wind, fertility, etc) and the basic social powers (such as military and royal protection) that are necessary for basic human & social survival. Where as the Buddhist gods are more refined & represent moral & meditative principles/archetypes.

Thank you,that was really helpful!
